# HashMap is showing only last entry

Tags: java, hashmap

Only last entry of `HashMap` is getting displayed.
My hashMap consists of keys of type employee and values of type hobby, but on displaying only last entry are getting displayed.

Please help me in removing errors from this code:

```
public void addEmployees(int a, HashMap<Employee,Hobby> hMap)
{
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    Hobby hob = new Hobby();
    Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner obj1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i =0; i<a ; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter id of employee:");
        int num = obj.nextInt();
        emp.setEmployeeId(num);

        System.out.println("Enter name of employee:");
        String str = obj1. nextLine();
        emp.setName(str);

        hob.enterHobby();
        hMap.put(emp,hob);
    }    
}


public static void main(String [] args)
{
    HashMap <Employee,Hobby> employeeName = new HashMap <Employee,Hobby>();
    System.out.println("Enter the number of employees you want to add");
    Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner obj1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = obj.nextInt();
    EmployeeManag emg = new EmployeeManag();
    emg.addEmployees(num,employeeName);
}


class Hobby
{
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void enterHobby()
    {
        Scanner obj1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Add Hobbie");
        String str = obj1.nextLine();
        arr.add(str);
    }

    public void displayHobbie()
    {
        for(String str : arr)
        {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}

class Employee
{

    private int employeeId;
    private String name;

    public int getEmployeeId() 
    {
        return employeeId;
    }
    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) 
    {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you're not adding the employes to the HashMap that you pass to your function, but to some other hash map

Comment: Have you overriden `equals` and `hashCode`? If not, learn what they do and how `HashMap` uses them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java HashMap "put" method in a for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671164/java-hashmap-put-method-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: You keep adding the same object as the key, so there is only one. It doesn't copy the object implicitly.

Comment: Unless you know what you are doing, don't use mutable objects for keys, or elements in sets.  They will just confuse you.

Comment: @hyde http://stackoverflow.com/users/1717300/hyde I have overriden equals and hashcode methods in employee class, such that my equals return true if and only if employee ids of two objects are same and hash code returns employee id itself.  but stil getting the problem. Though initialising employee and Hobby object inside for loop has solved the problem but should have worked for a single declaration of these objects outside for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create emp object inside for loop for each iteration.

```
public void addEmployees(int a, HashMap<Employee,Hobby> aList)
        {
           Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
           Scanner obj1 = new Scanner(System.in);

           for(int i =0; i<a ; i++)
             {
                Hobby hob = new Hobby();
                Employee emp = new Employee();
                System.out.println("Enter id of employee:");
                int num = obj.nextInt();
                emp.setEmployeeId(num);

                System.out.println("Enter name of employee:");
                String str = obj1. nextLine();
                emp.setName(str);

                hob.enterHobby();
                hMap.put(emp,hob);
              }    
          }
```

Comment: You need to create the `Hobby` in the loop as well, or modifying one employee's hobby will change them all.

Comment: Yes im sorry i missed it @Trengot